# Equation in Beamer

Tags: beamer

My script works fine, until I add frame with equation. 
My script:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Replace the \documentclass declaration above
% with the following two lines to typeset your 
% lecture notes as a handout:
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsopn} 



\section{Proposed Solution}
\subsection{ Model}
\begin{frame}{ Model}
\begin{block}{model XX}
     three factors
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1. 
        \item 2.
        \item 3.
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Formula}
    calculated in this equation
    \begin{equation}

            Total = \frac{1}{n}*\sum_{i=0}^n (eachnode_i) 

    \end{equation}

\end{block}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Empty lines are not allowed in the `equation` environment. Just remove the empty lines before and after the line starting with Total. You also deed to do add `\begin{document}` (before `\section`) and `\end{document` (at the end).

Comment: I got this, `Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason: The mathkerncmssi source file could not be found`, for `\end{document}` it is there

Comment: How do you compile your document? Did you try `xelatex` or `pdflatex`? Both should) work fine once you made the changes I described above.

Comment: I use`F6`, compile

Comment: (i) your code in question is not complete: mising are `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. (ii) i cant reproduce your errors (after removing empty lines in your equation). it works fine with `xelatex` and width `pdflatex`.

Comment: Off-topic: `amsopn` is loaded automatically by `amsmath`, and `amsfonts` is loaded automatically by `amssymb`. Hence, o need to load `amsfonts` and `amsopn` separately.

Comment: @Zarko - Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Mico, hm, does my comment solve op problem? so far op didn't  say anything.  anyway, than you you for your encouragement. i will consider this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- your code in question is not complete: missing are `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.
- in equations (math environments) are not allowed empty lines

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}  % loaded by amssymb, see Mico comment
%\usepackage{amsopn}    % loaded by amssymb

\begin{document}        % <--- added
\section{Proposed Solution}
\subsection{ Model}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Model}
\begin{block}{model XX}
     three factors
    \begin{itemize}
        \item 1.
        \item 2.
        \item 3.
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Formula}
    calculated in this equation
    \begin{equation}    % <--- deleted empty lines
            Total = \frac{1}{n}*\sum_{i=0}^n (eachnode_i)
    \end{equation}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}          % <--- added
```

- with considering aforementioned i can't reproduce your errors. it works fine with `xelatex` and width `pdflatex`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you guys, it works when delete empty lines, and add `\usepackage{sansmathaccent}`
`\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}`. Since MiKTeX not having the map file activated.